# Trouble getting a Java Applet program to open in my browser

Tags: java, applet

This is a program originally designed as a Java application.  I want it to work inside of an applet on a browser. The problem is that I cannot get my browser to successfully open and run the applet, this could be due to poorly written code, or simply that applet code is different than application code, if so where can I find "how to code in an applet"?

Should I use code for the applet expression(using mozilla) and specify the package, or leave it as it is as codebase?  Is it the code that is the problem?  Is it the main() method I'm calling?  Is the file supposed to have an extension of .class, because Netbeans automatically gives it .java even if I choose: New File -->  Java  --> Java Class?

I want to create an applet that prompts you to enter data and then it goes about the program and returns a result inside of the box.

All of the code isn't necessary, but I provided it all solely for information sake.

### HTML Code

```html
<applet codebase="SigmaExpression12.java" width= "500" height="400">
```

### Java Code

```
package sigmaexpression;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SigmaExpression12 extends Applet {


@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)

{ g.drawRect(0,0,250,100);
  g.setColor(Color.blue);
  g.drawString("hi.", 100, 100);
}
 public static void main() {

    double x;
    String answer1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the first term of your Sigma expression or series?");
    double y = Double.parseDouble(answer1);
    System.out.println("Your a(1) is :" + y);
    String answer2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the last term of your Sigma expression or series?");
    double z = Double.parseDouble(answer2);
    System.out.println("Your a(n) is :" + z);
    String answer3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the total term of numbers in your sequence?  If you don't know this, put 0.");
    double n = Double.parseDouble(answer3);
    System.out.println("Your n is :" + n);
      if(n==0)
    {
    String answer4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the increment of your numbers?  How much is it being increased, divided or multiplied by?");
    double i = Double.parseDouble(answer4);
    System.out.println("Your i is: " + i); 
    double nn = Math.round(n*100.0)/100.0;

      nn = (((z - y)/i) + 1);

    System.out.println("Your n is :" + nn); 

      x = (((y+z)/2) * nn );

      System.out.println("The sum of your numbers is: " + x);
    }

        x = (((y+z)/2) * n );

    System.out.println("The sum of your numbers is: " + x);

}
```

Comment: 1) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 2) Everything in that applet can be done using JavaScript, form fields, and possibly an HTML canvas for the custom painted part. Use pure HTML/JS for this one.

Answer (score 0):

your html:

```
<applet codebase="SigmaExpression12.java" width= "500" height="400">
```

should be more like:

```
<applet codebase="SigmaExpression12.class" width= "500" height="400">
```

You know, Java cannot run .java source code... It can only run the compiled stuff.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Java Applet Technology is dying. Not all browsers support it.
For instance Google Chrome does not support applets.

Secondly, to run applet you need to sign applet jar file (see jarsigner tool in JDK).

Third you need to add url applet location into Exception Site list (see it in Java Control Security Panel)

I recomend you take a look at [java web start](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml) instead.